# Is there a way to make a website go full screen (WITH user click)?

Tags: cross-platform, cross-browser, fullscreen

A client wants me to create a website that can go to fullscreen when the user clicks a "View in Fullscreen" button/link. The solution I've seen posted here and elsewhere:

```
window.open('www.example.com', 'title', 'type=fullWindow, fullscreen, scrollbars=yes');
```

seems to work spottily across browsers. Is there a better/more compatible solution? Maybe something involving Flash?

Thanks in advance. (And I know someone will suggest it, so please believe when I say that an alert box asking the user to press F11 has been suggested and shot down)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Users don't like it when websites decide for them how big the window should be, because it was usually used by bad advertisers trying to grab their attention. It was annoying enough that most browsers now disable window resizing. I'm not saying that you are being a bad citizen, but the browser has no way to differentiate between bad behavior and good behavior.

Comment: He is doing it in response to a button click, so it seems like the user would know what they are in for.

In general though, I have to agree, especially as I like to use high resolution large monitors to maximize the number of windows I have access at any time. A page that mazimizes itself is making assumptions about how I'm using my computer that it can't possibly know.

Comment: Apparently I can't spell "maximize".

Comment: I know, I'm not a fan of this either. But the client is adamant that it be included as a button in the site. If it can't be done, it can't be done - but I at least want to be able to say I exhausted all available options.

Answer (score 3):

i know this is an old post but it seems like you didn't get an answer. Here is a javascript function that i have used for many web applications when this function seems more necessary.

However like said above i would not use this functionality for a normal website as many users hate this functionality and will press f11 if they require it.

```
function fullScreen() {
    var el = document.documentElement
    , rfs = // for newer Webkit and Firefox
       el.requestFullScreen
    || el.webkitRequestFullScreen
    || el.mozRequestFullScreen
    || el.msRequestFullScreen
    ;

    if(typeof rfs!="undefined" && rfs){

        rfs.call(el);

    } else if(typeof window.ActiveXObject!="undefined"){

        // for Internet Explorer
        var wscript = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");

        if (wscript!=null) {
          wscript.SendKeys("{F11}");
        }
    }

}
```

And of course just include an onclick event on a button/link.

```
<button onclick="fullscreen();">click for fullscreen</button>
```

Comment: It's `requestFullscreen`, not `requestFullScreen`.

Answer (score 2):

The only truly cross-{platform, browser} approach I've seen is in flash, such as in this example [here](http://tinyurl.com/9m7pmj). Unfortunate, but true.

Incidentally, <kbd>F11</kbd> is a very platform specific answer anyway - it won't work on mac, for example.

Comment: I think this is what I'm looking for - but for it to function like I need it to, I need to wrap my HTML content in a flash player, correct? How would one do that? (Should I just ask that as a separate question?)

Comment: I believe to allow flash to go fullscreen, you pass a parameter to it in the html or javascript used to load the swf. Then on button click you can call some functions that allow the Stage to go fullscreen.  ON another note, chrome apps (applications that run in the browser, but are restricted to chrome) can go fullscreen too.